# Multiple choice question help please! Im lost!

Tags: statistics

The New Yorker, a local newspaper for Manhattan, New York conducted a poll on the 1996 governor's race. They took a random sample of 1200 voters in Manhattan and reported that 72% of those surveyed would vote for the Democratic candidate and announced that the margin of error was ±3% for 95% confidence in the survey results. At the same time, the Gallup organization also conducted a poll of 498 voters in Manhattan and reported that 68% of those surveyed would vote for the Democratic candidate and announced that the margin of error was ±4% for 95% confidence interval in the survey results.

Why does The New Yorker poll have a smaller margin of error than the Gallup poll in the information above?

The Gallup poll will have more bias present in the experiment 
 The Gallup poll is more honest because they are a nationally recognized organization

The New Yorker is the local paper, so it knows its own people better and will therefore be able to get more effective results

The Gallup organization is larger, therefore it will have a larger margin of error

The New Yorker took a larger sample size, so it will have a smaller margin of error

Comment: You are expected to answer that the larger sample gives the smaller margin of error (last item). That is almost true, although certain techniques, such as *stratified sampling*, can reduce margin of error without increasing the sample size.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to answer that the larger sample size leads to a smaller margin of error (so the last one of the choices).

That is in general true, at least for simple random sampling. However, there are techniques, such as *stratified sampling*, that can get more reliable information from a sample of $800$ than a simple random sample of, say, $1000$ people. For instance, suppose you know that the West side of the city is very stable in its voting patterns, while the East side is much more volatile. Then you can get better information by concentrating your sampling on the East side (you pretty much know how the West side will vote).

Sampling is a subtle business, and simple random sampling is certainly not the whole story. However, in the context in which you were asked the question, the answer is bigger is better.